# Android : decrypt and copy sqlite file from assets folder

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, 7zip

I have an encrypted sqlite db file that I am copying to the memory on install and decrypting.I am doing this as a safety feature to protect my db.
I encrypted the sqlite file using 7zip program using the following setups - I am only encrypting the file but not compressing it:[image: 7zip print screen encrypting the sqlite file]

Notice that I am using AES-256 encryption method.

I copied this file the the assets folder.

This is the class that I use to copy and decrypt the sqlite file.

```
public class AssetDatabaseOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "dictionary.db";
    private static final String DB_NAME_ENCRYPTED = "dictionary.7z";

    private Context context;

    public AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        File dbFileEncrypted = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME_ENCRYPTED);

        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {
                copyDatabase(dbFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException{

        Toast.makeText(context, "The language dictionary is getting copied to your local file. Please wait.\n This is done once when the app is ran for the first time.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME_ENCRYPTED);

        if (!dbFile.getParentFile().exists()) dbFile.getParentFile().mkdir();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

        // Length is 16 byte
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("mypassword".getBytes(),
                "AES_256");
        // Create cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES_256");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while ((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
            os.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "The application is ready for the first use .", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}
```

The main method that I am interested in is copyDatabase(...) .

The error that I am getting is that the table from the db can't be found "No such table..."- I conclude that the file is created but not properly.

Can you spot the error in the process.
Regards.

Comment: What is the point of the encryption? The password and algorithm are in your app. Anyone can decrypt the database whenever they want. Or, they can simply copy the database off a rooted device. Beyond that, your code has nothing to deal with the 7z format, and that is the format that your asset is in.

Comment: I can protect the app code by using proguard - that is where the password is.This will make it a bit more harder to get the files. My application must be 100% off line and I must find a way to protect the sqlite db.Since I didn't compress the file, the 7z format should not play any role - right!?

Comment: "that is where the password is" -- your password is still in plain text, even with ProGuard. "My application must be 100% off line and I must find a way to protect the sqlite db" -- by definition, that is not possible. If your program can get to the data, any human with access to the program can get to the data. "Since I didn't compress the file, the 7z format should not play any role - right!?" -- most likely, it plays a role.

Comment: Ok, in regard to 7z format, I went to using the application from https://www.aescrypt.com/download/ for sqlite encrypting - now the file is in the ".aes" format - dictionary.db.aes to be more exact . But again the same issue with the code, I can not read the table. This is not a full protection feature but at least someone will not be able to take the winrar  and extract all the files from the .apk file . So my goal right now is to get the db file correctly decrypted.

Comment: I have resolved the issue with by using https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/ . I used SQLiteStudio to create a crypted sqlite db and the library from the link to read it.